# What shell commands are executed by LyX View menus?

Tags: lyx, compiling, build-system

For a variety of reasons, I'm using LyX as my primary LaTeX document creation tool, but I want to avoid doing things or relying on features of LyX that make it hard to use other tools as well. While I've been able to configure LyX to make it possible to move the generated TeX into any other editor (e.g., I can simply paste my TeX code into TeXShop, and it works) I'm unclear on what command lines are required to perform various build tasks.

Is there a way to find out what command lines correspond to the various LyX "View" menu commands? Are these listed somewhere? For example, what commands (`pdflatex`? `biblatex`? etc.; with what arguments?) does the `View` > `View [PDF (pdflatex)]` menu command execute?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think these are the ones listed in Tools --> Preferences --> File Handling --> Converters (see screenshot at the bottom). There you can see the command line arguments used.

### $$-variables

The `$$<letter>` variables refer to the following (from the LyX Customization manual, found under Help --> Customization, section 3.3):

- `$$s` The LyX system directory
- `$$i` The input file
- `$$o` The output file
- `$$b` The base filename of the input file (i.e., without the extension)
- `$$p` The path to the input file
- `$$r` The path to the original input file (this is different from `$$p` when a chain of converters is called)
- `$$e` The iconv name for the encoding of the document.

### Extra flag

Quoting the manual mentioned above:

> In the **Extra Flag** field you can enter the following flags,
>   separated by commas:
>
> - `latex` This converter runs some form of LaTeX. This will make LyX's LaTeX error logs available.
> - `needaux` Needs the LaTeX `.aux` file for the conversion.
> - `xml` Output is XML.
>
> The following three flags are not really flags at all because they
>   take an argument in the **key = value** format:
>
> - `parselog` If set, the converter's standard error will be redirected to a file `infile.out`, and the script given as argument
>     will be run as:
>
>   ```
>   script < infile.out > infile.log.  The argument may contain `$$s`.
>   ```
> - `resultdir` The name of the directory in which the converter will dump the generated files. LyX will not create this directory, and it
>     does not copy anything into it, though it will copy this directory to
>     the destination. The argument may contain `$$b`, which will be
>     replaced by the base name of the input and output files, respectively,
>     when the directory is copied. Note that `resultdir` and `usetempdir`
>     make no sense together. The latter will be ignored if the former is
>     given.
> - `resultfile` Determines the output file name and may, contain `$$b`. Sensible only with `resultdir` and optional even then; if not
>     given, it defaults to `index`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Some other things must be going on too though. For example, how does LyX decide when to rebuild the bibliography: it seems to be necessary to close and reopen the LyX file to get this to happen? Also, of course, LyX must be appending to these in order to launch a viewer or save a file, or cache somewhere, when employing these converters in `Export` vs. `View` vs. `Update` commands. And: I assume `$$i` = source file name, `$$o` = output file name (though I don't understand how some converters can omit `$$i` if that's true), and it's not clear what `$$r` is.

Comment: Also (sorry) what does the "Extra flag" field do? In the example above `latex=pdflatex` is not a `pdflatex` option (that I can find in the [manual](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/pdflatex1.html)).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I assume LyX uses a script such as [`latexmk`](http://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk) in the background, that checks if extra runs of `pdflatex` or `bibtex` is needed. `-latex=pdflatex` may be an argument to such a script (`latexmk` has something like that). As for `$$r` and `$$s`, I cannot say. One could perhaps be filename without extension (e.g. `file` instead of `file.tex`). Converters without `$$i` could be wrongly configured, I suppose.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Help --> Customization, there is some info about this in section 3.3. I added most of this to the answer.

Comment: Good answer! Another way, although ad hoc, is to open LyX from the command line if you're on Linux. The terminal output often says what commands it runs. If you want all of the possible output, run using `lyx -dbg any`, which turns debugging on. You might want to redirect the output of this command to sort through the output because otherwise it will flash by. Similarly, you can go to View > Messages (don't forget to look at the Settings to control what output appears).